# Is there a way to see the permissions of all the intermediate directories of a path..?

Tags: bash, shell, permissions, files

I have a file path..
Is there any single command to see the file/directory permissions of all the intermediate directories in the path..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two oneliners. One `ls` call per path component:

```
$ (IFS=/; set -f -- $PWD; for arg; do path="${path%/}/$arg"; ls -dal "$path"; done)
```

Output:

```
# drwxr-xr-x  31 root  admin  1122  4 Nov 22:08 /
# drwxr-xr-x  9 root  admin  306  3 Nov 17:36 /Users
# drwxr-xr-x+ 67 janmoesen  staff  2278  7 Nov 14:46 /Users/janmoesen
# drwxr-xr-x+ 53 janmoesen  staff  1802  4 Nov 22:07 /Users/janmoesen/Sites
# drwxr-xr-x  28 janmoesen  staff  952  7 Nov 15:01 /Users/janmoesen/Sites/example.com
```

With just one call to `ls` with all paths:

```
$ (IFS=/; set -f -- $PWD; for arg; do path="${path%/}/$arg"; paths+=("$path"); done; ls -dal "${paths[@]}")
```

Output:

```
# drwxr-xr-x  31 root       admin  1122  4 Nov 22:08 /
# drwxr-xr-x   9 root       admin   306  3 Nov 17:36 /Users
# drwxr-xr-x+ 67 janmoesen  staff  2278  7 Nov 14:46 /Users/janmoesen
# drwxr-xr-x+ 53 janmoesen  staff  1802  4 Nov 22:07 /Users/janmoesen/Sites
# drwxr-xr-x  28 janmoesen  staff   952  7 Nov 15:01 /Users/janmoesen/Sites/example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Gilles! Could you give an example of how globbing can mess up the `set --` without `-f`? I tried with a directory `a[bar]` on the same level as directories `ab`, `aa` and `ar`, but did not succeed. (EDIT: Succeed in failing, that is. I want to know how it goes wrong.)

Answer (score 12):

Linux comes with the [`namei`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/namei) command which is mainly useful to display symbolic links in paths, but can also show ownership.

```
$ namei -nom ~   
f: /home/gilles
 drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
 drwxr-sr-x root   staff  home
 drwxr-xr-x gilles gilles gilles
```

Otherwise, here's a way to iterate over the successive directories containing a given file (not the only one, as other answers on this page illustrate) and list their contents.

```
d=$PWD; set /;
while [ -n "$d" ]; do set -- "$@" "$d/"; d=${d%/*}; done;
ls -ld "$@"
```

Note that this listing can be a little misleading in the presence of symbolic links. For example, if `/foo/bar` is a symbolic link to `/hello/world` which is itself a symbolic link to `/one/two`, and all of `/foo`, `/hello` and `/world` are world-readable (say mode 755) but `/hello` is not readable to user Alice, then Alice won't be able to reach `/foo/bar`, yet the listing above will show only world-readable directories.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

(( $# )) || set -- "$PWD"

IFS='/'
for _arg; do
    if ! [[ -e "${_arg}" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "${_arg} does not exist!"
        exit 1
    fi

    read -ra _dirs <<< "${_arg}"
    (( _length = ${#_dirs[@]} + 1 ))
    for (( _offset = 2 ; _offset < _length ; _offset++ )); do
        _current_dir="${_dirs[*]::_offset}"
        _perms=$(ls -ld "${_current_dir}" | awk '{ print $1" "$3" "$4 }')
        printf '%s %s\n' "${_perms}" "${_current_dir}"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a short way to do so. For this task I use a shell script, you may find useful, too:

```
 #!/bin/ksh

 if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    set "$PWD"
  fi

 for path in "$@"
  do
   while true
    do
     ls -ld "$path"
     if [ -z "$path" -o "$path" = . -o "$path" = / ]
      then
        break
      fi
     path=$(dirname "$path")
    done
  done
```

**EDIT**: Using an `until` loop omits the need for the break ...

```
 #!/bin/ksh

 [ $# -eq 0 ] && set "$PWD"

 for path
  do
   until test -z "$path" -o "$path" = . -o "$path" = /
    do
     ls -ld "$path"
     path=$(dirname "$path")
    done
  done
```

Comment: Your script will break on certain paths with special characters.

Comment: ok - added some more quotes. But for such rare occasions and no changes made to anything I lived with that.

Comment: It would be simpler to leverage `IFS` for splitting on `/`, like [janmoesen does](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24102/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-permissions-of-all-the-intermediate-directories-of-a-p/24113#24113).

Answer (score 0):

Not so complicated, but this would help you I guess.

```
find . -type d -exec ls -lrt {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### List permissions of every directory in a directory path (up or down)

```
alias dirls='_dirls() { path="$(realpath $1)";_path="";for i in " " ${path//\// }; do _path="$_path$i/"; ls -ld $_path; done; unset _path; };_dirls'

alias dirls2='_dirls2() { path="$(realpath $1)"; while [[ "$path" != "/" ]]; do ls -ld "$path"; path="$(dirname "$path")"; done; ls -ldh /; };_dirls2'
```

---

```
eg:

# dirls /usr/local/bin
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root 236 Nov 11 19:01 /
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 181 Dec  7 11:50 /usr/
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 205 Nov 22 14:06 /usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Dec  5 12:19 /usr/local/bin/

# dirls2 /usr/local/bin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Dec  5 12:19 /usr/local/bin
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 205 Nov 22 14:06 /usr/local
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 181 Dec  7 11:50 /usr
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root 236 Nov 11 19:01 /
```